# Dalvik Mismatched Stack Depths - Error Code 1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik

I'm having an issue with integrating the Aviary SDK.

Upon compilation I receive the following error:

```
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
Dx mismatched stack depths

Dx underlay stack:
overlay stack:
stack[top0]: Lcom/aviary/android/feather/headless/moa/MoaAction;
...while merging to block 0048
...while working on block 0040
...while working on method clone:()Ljava/lang/Object;
...while processing clone ()Ljava/lang/Object;
...while processing com/aviary/android/feather/headless/moa/MoaAction.class

Dx 1 error; aborting
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error
```

I've tried removing all the jars from my Java Build Path->Libraries, cleaning and the re-adding them.

Under Order and Export, Android 4.4.2, src, gen, Android Private Libraries, and Android Dependencies are checked.
There is nothing under Java Build Path->Projects.

The SDK in question is a library, and not a JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough it seems the NewRelic library was causing the issue. Removing just that library, building, and then re-adding it seems to have resolved it.

Everytime the app is cleaned, the issue comes up again though.

Answer (score 1):

I did get this error also after running proguard when creating the DEX file. I updated the SDK proguard to 5.3.3 and it did not show up anymore.